# Node.js: TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

I was having another error (**throw new Error('Most middleware (like ' + name + ') is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately.**) and the fix was to go down a version in express "`npm install express@">=3.0.0 <4.0.0" --save`". But after I did that, i got this error: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined*. Dont know what I should do, tried to installing express again hoping for the error to go away by getting my other version back, but that didn't seem to work.

This is the whole error:

```
express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option app.js:9:9
C:\Users\...\Kea_DAT_Node_2020_Spring\1\7._Authh\routes\auth.js:14
route.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {

TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Osvald\Documents\NODEJS\Kea_DAT_Node_2020_Spring\1\7._Authh\routes\auth.js:14:7)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Osvald\Documents\NODEJS\Kea_DAT_Node_2020_Spring\1\7._Authh\app.js:37:19)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)←[39m


      ^
```

---

Auth.js file

```
const route = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User.js");

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const saltRounds = 12;

const myPlaintextPassowrd = "heyjohey";
const someOtherPlantextPassword = "not_bacon";

bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassowrd, saltRounds).then((hash) => {
    console.log(hash);
});

route.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {

    // what fields do we need to sign up?
    // username, password, repeat password
    const { username, password, passwordRepeat } = req.body;
    const isPasswordTheSame = password === passwordRepeat;

    if (username && password && isPasswordTheSame) {
        // password requirements
        if (password.length < 8) {
            return res.status(400).send({ response: "Password does not fulfill the requirements" });
        } else {
            try {
            const userFound = await User.query().select().where({ 'username': username }).limit(1);
            if (userFound.length > 0) {
                return res.status(400).send({ response: "User already exists" });
            } else {
                const defaultUserRoles = await Role.query().select().where({ role: 'USER' });
                const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);
                const createdUser = await User.query().insert({
                    username,
                    password: hashedPassword,
                    roleId: defaultUserRoles[0].id
                });

                return res.send({ response: "User has been created with the username" + username });
            }

            } catch (error) {
                return res.status(500).send({ response: "Something went wrong with the database" });
            }
        }
    } else if (password && passwordRepeat && !isPasswordTheSame) {
        return res.status(400).send({ response: "Passwords do not match. Fields: password and passwordRepeat" });
    } else {
        return res.status(404).send({ response: "Missing fields: username, password, passwordRepeat" });
    }
});

route.post("/logout", (req, res) => {
    return res.send({ response: "OK OK "})
});


module.export = route;
```

Comment: Use this - `var express = require('express')`
`var router = express.Router()`

Comment: You did get method right ?